# bash wait still waits for a terminated (piped) process

Tags: bash

I've a bash script similar to this one:

```
#!/bin/sh -x
...
midori -e Fullscreen -a "myurl" 2>&1 | grep -qe "===RESTART===" &
GREP_PID=$!

.. do other stuff with midori etc.

#wait until midori send ===RESTART===
echo Wait for $GREP_PID
wait $GREP_PID
killall -TERM midori
...
```

Most of them work as expected. But the latest `wait` will not unblock, after the grep process is dead. I've checked with `pstree` for the running process. so midori and grep are startet correct. After a while midori send `===RESTART===` and the `grep` process is terminated (`grep` is no more visible with `pstree`). But the `wait` never finishes.

Whats is the reason for this? How to "enforce" the wait to continue, when the `grep` process is terminated?

Comment: `grep` shouldn't complete before `midori` does (unless `midori` *explicitly* closed its own standard output), so the `killall` command seems unnecessary. (I wouldn't expect `midori` to still be running if `grep` had, in fact, completed.)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if your `$GREP_PID` contains right value. Try:

```
(midori -e Fullscreen -a "myurl" 2>&1 | grep -qe "===RESTART===")&
```

Answer (score 1):

See following example:

```
[STEP 105] # sleep 1000 | sleep 10 &
[1] 45230
[STEP 106] # echo $!
45230
[STEP 107] # ps p 45230
   PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 45230 pts/8    S      0:00 sleep 10
[STEP 108] #
```

As we can see, for `command1 ... | command2 ... &`, the `$!` is the PID of `command2`. So when `wait $!` completes, only `command2` has exited and `command1` may still be running. So if you want to wait for both `command1` and `command2` you shoud use the *job ID* (`%%`, `%1`, `%2`, ...). Or you can just run `wait` (without a parameter) to wait for all jobs.